# What does “lower status” mean in “Boston house prices dataset”?

Tags: data-request, python, documentation

scikit-learn comes with [Boston house prices dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#boston-dataset). One of the features is LSTAT, which means "Percentage of lower status of the population".

What does "lower status" mean there?

Does it mean something like "low incoming"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From dataset documentation in Table IV of Harrison & Rubin (1978), LSTAT is defined as:

> Proportion of population that is lower status = 1/2
>   (proportion of adults without, some high school education and proportion of male workers classified as
>   laborers). The logarithmic specification implies that
>   socioeconomic status distinctions mean more in the
>   upper brackets of society than in the lower classes. Source: 1970 U. S. Census

Harrison Jr, David, and Daniel L. Rubinfeld. "Hedonic housing prices and the demand for clean air." Journal of environmental economics and management 5, no. 1 (1978): 81-102.